# Is it a faux pas to ask for a colleague's figure in a separate but related publication?

Tags: publications, citations, copyright

I'm an undergraduate with virtually no experience with the expectations of academia (so I apologize in advance for the silly question). I'm finishing up a paper describing my research and would like to include a figure to describe something in my "Background" section.

There is a graduate student in my lab who has a paper dealing with the background topic and has a perfect image that I'd like to use as said figure. The paper has been accepted but not yet published. Would I be violating some protocol if I asked to use the identical figure? If not, what is the proper way to attribute the figure to the original source? In the caption?

Comment: "I want you to know that I've been admiring your figure...". Yep, that's a faux pas.

Answer (score 10):

You can always ask, then it is the choice of the author to accept or not. As for the citation, if the paper is accepted but not published, you can have a note in the citation "to appear". For instance, your text could like:

> Following [Alice12], we describe ... as illustrated in Fig.1.
>
> [Alice12] Alice, paper, journal, accepted, to appear.

Comment: I would give credit much more explicitly in the caption: "Figure from [Alice12], used with author's permission".  Don't lie.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that you *need* to include the following: (1) the citation, (2) the phrase "used with permission". Failing to do so could place you in plagiarism territory, as the figure was taken from another paper without proper referencing.

Comment: But, OP is asking about using an identical figure, not the exact one, right?

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham According to my dictionary, identical means: "similar in every detail; exactly alike"  So "identical figure" means the same one.

Comment: (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/identical) In anyway permission is needed.

Comment: One note: if the paper is accepted for publication, it is possible that the original author has signed a publication/copyright waiver for the journal. In which case to re-use the identical figure one would need not only permission of the author, but also the permission of the _publisher_.

Comment: (See, for example, [AAAS's policy for re-using material appearing in _Science_](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/about/permissions.xhtml#reqperm).

Comment: @eykanal: Could you elaborate on why "used with permission" is necessary? I do not deny there may be some convoluted legal reasoning behind this, it's just that I'm regularly amused by that statement, wondering "So what? Why are you telling us? Why should I, as a reader, be interested in the fact that there is a bilateral agreement between you and the creator of the figure?" In any case, I fail to see how there could be any chance to be placed in plagiarism territory when the figure caption literally says that the figure was copied from a particular external source. Legal copyright ...

Comment: ... infringement, maybe yes (because indicating the source does not automatically mean having the right to copy), but plagiarism (as in, the ethical failure to wrongfully reproduce someone else's work as one's own, or one's own work while pretending it is novel)?

Comment: I agree with O. R. Mapper: Whether you have the author's permission is important for matters of copyright (figures are copyrighted, as far as I'm aware) (also note that it's the copyright holder's perminssion that is important, which often will not be the author), what counts for issues of plagiarism is just unambiguous attribution of the figure to the author.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - See my comment, "failure to do so could place you in plagiarism territory." Do not use other people's work without their permission, many problems may arise.

Comment: @eykanal: Yes, that's exactly what I do not understand. I fail to see how anyone could call out plagiarism (in the scientific sense) when the caption explicitly contains the original source, thereby making it clear the author does *not* claim to have created the figure, or that it is new. Also, "Do not use other people's work without their permission" is unquestionably true, but we normally don't point out we're allowed to do what we're doing. For a sentence like "Survey results were compiled in Google Docs.", no-one would expect or request the remark "used with permission". Likewise, ...

Comment: ... a paper that says "We used the algorithm by McDuff [42].", the addition "with permission" is not expected, either. So, why would it be different for figure captions? What makes the information that the author had a permission to use the figure valuable *to the reader*, when the author's permission to use, for instance, their text processing software is simply taken for granted?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Lets take this discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower).

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that an identical image, either modified from the original or made based on the original, is being used, here is a better way of citing the source.

This is from [APA](http://library.nmu.edu/guides/userguides/apacitingtables.htm),

> **Material adapted from a journal article. Note format is different from References.**
>
> Figure #. Description/Note. Adapted from “Title of Article,” by F. M.
>   Author and C. D. Author, year, Title of Journal, volume, p. xx.
>   Copyright year by the Name of Copyright Holder. Adapted [or Reprinted]
>   with permission.

See this from [Wiley](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CEwQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fauthorservices.wiley.com%2FPermissions%2520Guidelines%2520for%2520Authors%2520PDF.pdf&ei=9b1QUJnfIImHrAer1ICAAg&usg=AFQjCNGpMrV1upRnZFBdtA7PzrKjeOxmGw&sig2=W2wQcx-T972xw7kqUJlBFQ)

> If you wish to republish an already modified figure or table,
>   permission should be obtained from the source of the modified item,
>   but the credit line should include reference to the original source(s)
>   of the material as well as to the source of the modification. If you
>   wish to republish a previously published figure or table originally
>   compiled from data from other sources, permission for its re-use must
>   be obtained from whoever owns the copyright in the compilation. The
>   credit line should include reference to the source of the compilation,
>   and to the sources of the original data by using the words ‘Based on’,
>   ‘Compiled from’, or similar, or by using the credit line appearing on
>   the original compilation.
>
> If you wish to make changes or further changes to content which is
>   already in the process of being cleared, you may need to reapply for
>   permission as it is possible that the copyright owner will not like
>   the new proposed alterations and they are entitled to refuse
>   permission.

See also [MTU](http://www.mtu.edu/gradschool/administration/academics/thesis-dissertation/copyright/faq/)

> **I modified a figure from a journal article. Do I need to ask for permission?**
>
> It depends. Significant modifications result in a figure that is
>   uniquely yours. The source of the inspiration or base of the figure
>   must be acknowledged in your caption. To clarify the source and figure
>   creator, we recommend a credit line in your caption similar to,
>   "Figure adapted by author from SOURCE." where SOURCE would be replaced
>   with an appropriate citation. If the figure is just a tracing of the
>   original figure, or does not contain a significant amount of
>   creativity, you have not created it, and must ask for permission.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly okay to ask for the figure knowing well that the other person may not give.
I assume you would get the permission to use the figure. As @eykanal, pointed out we need to put the phrase "used with permission" or write "Source: Citation" in the figure caption.

Example below:

[image]

Figure 1: An example flow chart [Source: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2003/images/jw-0502-java1013.gif]

You may also write
Figure 1: An example flow chart [Source: Alice et al. to appear in Journal,Year]

Comment: This is fine if you are using the exact one. But what if a modified version is used?

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham If it's modified in a substantial, e.g., conceptual way, then you could say "based on..."; otherwise I would just say that you copied the figure.